# How can I fix a USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED error using SOAP?

Tags: c#, soap, authorization

I'm trying to call an API using C# code samples downloaded from https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-DotNet. I'm using SOAP.

After registration, I received the following authentication info:

> Key: V1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:PUBLIC:EXT
>   Shared Secret: yyyyyyyy

Therefore, I have configured my *SACSConfig.properties* as follows:

```
userId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
group=PUBLIC  
domain=EXT  
clientSecret=yyyyyyyy  
environment=https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com
```

Then I ran the sample application as follows:

1. Run
2. Click on "SOAP Workflow"
3. Click on "submit"

The call to the `SessionCreateRQAsync` API is successful, but in the method `PassengerDetailsContactActivity.RunAsync` an error occurs when the following statement is executed:

```
PassengerDetailsRS response = service.PassengerDetailsRQ(request);
```

The error is:

> com.sabre.universalservices.base.security.AuthorizationException:
>   errors.authorization.USG_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED

Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?